# check of a java awt 2D game, jbutton background update problem

Tags: java, 2d, awt, jbutton

i'm posting a simple game code, written in java. It took my hours today to write this but now i'm stuck! The problem is, in the second level of this game (after failure or success) i can't see the red tiles. It works only the first time.

games logic:
it starts up with a 3x3 matrix and rebound the dimension of this matrix in case of success (testing the ability of memory, memorising the coordinates of red tiles in 1200 ms). So we show the red tiles first, than we check the estimations. If there became a wrong try, failure!. If it is a bigger matrix than 3x3, it gets smaller.

the code is a little bit long but just one class, so it is so easy yo execute it. If you have time i would be appreciate.

So there it goes:

```
package skeleton;


public class Memory extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5963518754230629235L;

private static int minDimX = 3, minDimY = 3;
private static int maxDimX = 15, maxDimY = 15;
private static int counter = 13;
private static int memoriseTime = 1200; // milliseconds
private static int memGridWidthX = 60;
private static int memGridWidthY = 60;

private JPanel centerPanel;
private JButton memTile;
private Random generator;
private int memGridDimX, memGridDimY, coef, numberOfMemTilesToGuess;
int[][] memTileCoordinates;
int[] randomNums;

Border grayBorder = LineBorder.createGrayLineBorder();


public Memory(int xDim, int yDim) {

    waitALittleBit(1300);

    memGridDimX = xDim;
    memGridDimY = yDim;
    coef = 3;
    numberOfMemTilesToGuess = memGridDimX*memGridDimY / coef;

    centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(memGridDimY, memGridDimX, 0, 0));

    add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    System.out.println("int[" + memGridDimX + "][" + memGridDimY + "] array is created ");

    randomNums = new int[numberOfMemTilesToGuess];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfMemTilesToGuess ; i ++) {
        System.out.println("> we are in for the "+ (i+1) +". time!");

        int randomNum;
        boolean randomNumberAlreadySelected = false;

        do {
            randomNum = calculateARandomNumber(memGridDimX * memGridDimY);
            if (i != 0) { //for the first time, we don't need to compare any numbers
                randomNumberAlreadySelected = isThisRandomNumberExistInAlreadyFoundRandomNumbersArray(randomNum, randomNums, i);
                if (randomNumberAlreadySelected) 
                    System.out.println("######## RECALCULATING RANDOM NUMBER !! ##########");
                else
                    System.out.println("They are not equal, go on!");
            }
        } while (randomNumberAlreadySelected);

        randomNums[i] = (Integer)randomNum;
    }

    //show the memory tiles
    setMemTiles(randomNums, true);

    waitALittleBit(memoriseTime);

    //hide the memory tiles
    setMemTiles(randomNums, false);

}

private int calculateARandomNumber(int limit) {

    generator = new Random();

    System.out.println("* Calculating random number which is smaller than " + memGridDimX * memGridDimY);
    int randomNum = generator.nextInt() % (memGridDimX * memGridDimY);
    System.out.println("- Calculated random number: " + randomNum);
    if (randomNum < 0) {
        System.out.println(".. it is negative, so we add: " + memGridDimX * memGridDimY);
        randomNum += memGridDimX * memGridDimY;         
    }

    System.out.println(".. and we add 1 to have a grid array between 1 and 12");
    randomNum += 1;
    System.out.println(".. and our new random number is: " + randomNum);

    return randomNum;
}

private boolean isThisRandomNumberExistInAlreadyFoundRandomNumbersArray(int number, int[] numberArr, int numberArrSize) {

    for (int j = 0 ; j < numberArrSize ; j ++) {
        System.out.println("# Comparing random number: " + number + " and " + (j+1) + ". random number selected earlier: " + numberArr[j]);
        if (number == numberArr[j])
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private void setMemTiles(int[] randomNums, boolean showMemTiles) {

    centerPanel.removeAll();

    memTileCoordinates = new int[randomNums.length][2];

    for (int i = 1 ; i <= memGridDimY ; i ++) {
        for (int j = 1 ; j <= memGridDimX ; j ++) {

            int rnX = -1; 
            int rnY = -1;
            boolean isMemTile = false;
            for (int k = 0 ; k < randomNums.length ; k ++) {
                int rn = randomNums[k];

                if (rn % memGridDimX == 0) {
                    rnY = rn / memGridDimX;
                    rnX = memGridDimX;
                } else {
                    rnY = rn / memGridDimX + 1;
                    rnX = rn % memGridDimX;
                }
                if (i == 1 && j == 1 && !showMemTiles) { //do it once
                    System.out.println("*********      ************");
                    System.out.println("Random label number: " + rn + " and it's position in the grid: " + rnX + "," + rnY);

                    memTileCoordinates[k][0] = rnX;
                    memTileCoordinates[k][1] = rnY;
                    System.out.println("> Memory Tiles coordinates: " + memTileCoordinates[k][0] + "," + memTileCoordinates[k][1]);
                    System.out.println("> Memory Tiles length: " + memTileCoordinates.length);
                    System.out.println("*********      ************");
                }

                if (rnX == j && rnY == i) 
                    isMemTile = true;
            }

            memTile = new JButton();
            if (isMemTile) {
                update(getGraphics());
                if (showMemTiles) {
                    memTile.setBackground(Color.red); 
                    System.out.println("%%%% PAINTING MEM TILES IN RED %%%%");
                } else 
                    memTile.setBackground(Color.white);
                update(getGraphics());
            } else 
                memTile.setBackground(Color.white);
            if (!showMemTiles) // we listen actions after the memory tiles disappears
                memTile.addActionListener(this);

            centerPanel.add(memTile);
            update(getGraphics());
        }
    }

    setJPanelSettings();
}

private void setJPanelSettings() {

    setSize(memGridDimX * memGridWidthX, memGridDimY * memGridWidthY);
    setTitle("Memory :: " + memGridDimX + "x" + memGridDimY);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

private void waitALittleBit(long waitingMillisSeconds) {
    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long t1 ;

    do {
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } while (t1 - t0 < waitingMillisSeconds);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Memory(minDimX,minDimY);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    System.out.println(">>> An action came >>>");

    JButton memTile = (JButton) e.getSource();
    Dimension size = memTile.getSize();

    int chosenMemTileDimX = memTile.getX();
    int chosenMemTileDimY = memTile.getY();
    int chosenMemTilePosX = chosenMemTileDimX / size.width + 1; // we add 1 becausee we present our tile numbers as 1:1, 1:2, ... ( instead of 0:0,0:1, ... ) 
    int chosenMemTilePosY = chosenMemTileDimY / size.height + 1;

    System.out.println("Chosen Tile's x dimension: " + chosenMemTileDimX + " ans y dimension: " + chosenMemTileDimY);
    System.out.println("Chosen Tile's width: " + size.width + " and height: " + size.height);
    System.out.println("Chosen Tile's coordinates: " + chosenMemTilePosX + ", " + chosenMemTilePosY);

    boolean tileIsMemTile = false;

    System.out.println("Memory Tiles Coordinates: ");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < memTileCoordinates.length ; i ++) {

        int memTileDimX = memTileCoordinates[i][0];
        int memTileDimY = memTileCoordinates[i][1];
        System.out.println("x: " + memTileDimX + ", y: " + memTileDimY);
        if (chosenMemTilePosX == memTileDimX && chosenMemTilePosY == memTileDimY)
            tileIsMemTile = true;
    }

    if (tileIsMemTile) {
        System.out.println("!!! Right Tile !!!");
        memTile.setBackground(Color.red);
        numberOfMemTilesToGuess -= 1;
        System.out.println("It rest " + numberOfMemTilesToGuess + " tiles to guess");
    } else {
        System.out.println("!!! Wrong Tile !!!");
        Icon falseTileIcon;
        try {
            falseTileIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("wrong.png"));
            if (falseTileIcon.getIconHeight() > 0)
                memTile.setIcon(falseTileIcon);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            memTile.setBackground(Color.black);
        }
        update(getGraphics()); // good trick!!
        waitALittleBit(1000);

        //TODO !!! FAILED IN LEVEL MESSAGE !!!
        dispose();

        if (memGridDimX == minDimX && ( memGridDimY == minDimY || memGridDimY == minDimY + 1))  
            new Memory(minDimX, minDimY);
        else if (memGridDimX == memGridDimY)
            new Memory(memGridDimX - 1, memGridDimY);
        else
            new Memory(memGridDimX, memGridDimY -1);
    }

    System.out.println(">>> Action processed >>>");

    if (numberOfMemTilesToGuess == 0) {
        System.out.println("\n END OF THE LEVEL");
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you guessed all the tiles without error !! \n");

        dispose();
        //TODO  !!!! SHOW INTERLEVEL INFORMATION !!!!

        if (memGridDimX != maxDimX && memGridDimY != maxDimY) {
            if (memGridDimX == memGridDimY)
                new Memory(memGridDimX, memGridDimY + 1);
            else
                new Memory(memGridDimX + 1, memGridDimY);
        } else
            System.out.println("You have a really good memory my friend!");
    }
}}
```

I used *update(getGraphics());* many times, it was just for a test...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: After my last edit, i tried to replace "update(getGraphics());" after the "setMemTiles(randomNums, true);" method, it worked!

Comment: Actually it doesn't work sometimes, so i need to improve this code.

Comment: "I used update(getGraphics()); .."  And that is the beginning of the problems with that code.  Never call getGraphics().  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ in the Java Tutorials for details.  Note that the 262 lines of code show 37 compilation errors.  For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: i woke up now, after breakfast i will look into that. But i didn't understand "37 compilation errors"! i don't get any! how come you get some much errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use LWJGL, which is a java game library.

https://www.lwjgl.org

Answer (score 2):

You where told in your last posting to NOT use the update() method.

```
do 
{         
    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();     
} 
while (t1 - t0 < waitingMillisSeconds);
```

Also, never use a tight loop like that. Its just as bad as using Thread.sleep(...);

You where given suggestions in your last posting!

Answer (score 1):

Some of the issues may be due to the thread on which the various bit of code run. The first time through you are running on the "Main" thread, and to be completely correct calls to update the AWT/Swing GUI should be done using the "Event Dispatcher Thread".

The `actionPerformed` method is called from the "Event Dispatcher Thread" and so then the second time you call into the constructor for `Memory` you are in this thread.

Also, aside from the fact you have implemented a  delay with a spin-loop, which is not efficient; you should not delay the "Event Dispatcher Thread".

See this short overview: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/swing_ui.shtml